# Understanding a classical execution context example

Tags: javascript

So I was reading this [blog](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/) about the execution context in javascript. After it I tried to understand a typical closure/EC example:

http://jsfiddle.net/s3kpmz33/

```
function foo() {
    var foos = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          foos.push(function() {
             alert(i);
           });
       }
    return foos;
}

var foos = foo();

foos[0]();
foos[1]();
foos[2]();

//All alert 3
```

I think that, if I understood this correctly, `i` is 3 because of closures. At the time the functions will execute they will look outside their current scope, in `foo`'s scope, to find the variable i, and they find that it's 3 by the time they get executed.

I then fixed it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/s3kpmz33/2/

```
function foo() {
    var foos = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           (function bar(k) {
               foos.push(function _bar() {
                  alert(k);
               })
           })(i);
       }
    return foos;
}

var foos = foo();

foos[0]();
foos[1]();
foos[2]();

//Correctly alert 0, 1, 2
```

Now, I believe that the reason behind this is because every `_bar` function now looks to the `bar` function scope, and BECAUSE this was an iife, or any function that would get executed with the value I want (previously declared function for example as @Quentin pointed out), they all created their OWN local copy of the value of `i` and assigned it to the local variable `k`.

Am I correct in my assumption? I realize I may not have explained it very clearly, because I don't feel like I understand it well enough. If I made a mistake in my reasoning, please correct me.

If you could improve my reasoning in more simple words, this would also be much appreciated for me and any fellow programmers who come here looking for answers.

Comment: I recommend you open your debugger tools, put some `debugger;` statements at the beginning of each `function` and try to run each of the scripts in JSFiddle and look what the scope overview says whenever a `debugger;` statement is encountered (add some meaningless variable declarations like `var a='test';` as well, so that you know which function you are in). It’s probably best to find out yourself, how JavaScript acts in those cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> BECAUSE this was an iife

It doesn't need to be an IIFE. You could have called a previously declared function instead.

```js
function alerter_factory(value_to_alert) {
  return function() {
    alert(value_to_alert);
  }
}

function foo() {
  var foos = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    foos.push(alerter_factory(i));
  }
  return foos;
}

var foos = foo();

foos[0]();
foos[1]();
foos[2]();
```

> they all created their OWN local copy of i and assigned it to the local variable k.

Close.

They have their own local copy of the **value** that was in `i` assigned to a local `k` variable.

Comment: true, I've edited my post to make that more clear for any future readers

Comment: "You could have called a previously declared function instead.", this is because of the fact that you execute it immediately though, right?

Comment: @NexusDuck — Because it is executed with the value you want. If you use a previously defined function then it isn't executed immediately (since the "immediately" in IIEF means "at the moment that the function is created")

Comment: aye, what I meant to say was that it got executed during the iteration of the `for` loop, therefore copying over the correct value of `i`